# how to achieve this in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have a two table table

Table1:

```
id   |  name   |  score | sports
hh-a | ben     |  67    | football
gy-a | jen     |  98    | criket
df-r | jay     |  56    | football
jf-a | mic     |  87    | cricket
yu-r | bal     |  98    | football
gt-a | gal     |  96    | football
dr-a | pal     |  46    | football
```

Table 2:

```
 captain_name |vicecaptain |  sports   
   df-r       | gt-a       |  football
```

I want to insert columns in table 1 named "is_captain" and "is_vicecaptain" and with the help of table 2 put 1 if yes else 0 for whoever plays sports= football

Comment: This is a basic [multi table update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)? What have you tried?

Comment: i don't know how to process this .. I got 2nd table by using multiple level self join but I am not able to process that whole table 2 . whatever i have asked its just a one small piece which i am stucked on

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: *I want to insert columns in table 1 named "is_captain" and "is_vicecaptain"* Do you really want to change the structure of the table? Maybe you need to obtain the output of the query with additional columns only?

Comment: Is it possible that some value is present in table2 twice (in captain_name and/or in |vicecaptain)?

Comment: no its unique @akina

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.*, 
       COALESCE(table1.id = table2.captain_name, 0) is_captain, 
       COALESCE(table1.id = table2.vicecaptain, 0) is_vicecaptain
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id IN (table2.captain_name, table2.vicecaptain)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: @AmitVerma I prefer to explain specific obscure points at the request of the OP or another participant. Guessing what might be incomprehensible to someone is a thankless task. PS. I do not see what is unclear in my query. Unless, of course, someone don't even try to understand it.